# Dividing a text file into two different parts

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have written a simple script to collect a list of titles from the JSON file and generated a text file containing the list.

The result is as follows:

```
Animal geography
Autobiogeography
Chorography
Economic geography
Footloose industry
Geomorphometry
Health geography
Human geography
Military geography
Philosophy of geography
Physical geography
Political geography
Regional geography
Satirical cartography
Settlement geography
Transport geography
Vernacular geography
Visual geography
Category:Cartography
Category:Economic geography
Category:Geodemography
Category:Human geography
Category:Military geography
Category:Physical geography
Category:Political geography
Category:Regional geography
Category:Settlement geography
Category:Topography
Category:Toponymy
Category:Transportation geography
Category:Vernacular geography
Category:Geography by place
```

**Problem:**

The problem that I am facing right now is how to split the text file into two parts:

The first part is text file containing :

```
Animal geography
Autobiogeography
Chorography
Economic geography
Footloose industry
Geomorphometry
Health geography
Human geography
Military geography
Philosophy of geography
Physical geography
Political geography
Regional geography
Satirical cartography
Settlement geography
Transport geography
Vernacular geography
Visual geography
```

And a second text file containing those which begins with the word Category:

```
Category:Cartography
Category:Economic geography
Category:Geodemography
Category:Human geography
Category:Military geography
Category:Physical geography
Category:Political geography
Category:Regional geography
Category:Settlement geography
Category:Topography
Category:Toponymy
Category:Transportation geography
Category:Vernacular geography
Category:Geography by place
```

I am totally at a lost on how to do it. Please advice.

Sorry for the confusing title. I have no idea how to explain my problem.

Thank you.

**Edit**

For example I have extracted all the titles from this API (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3ABranches%20of%20geography&cmlimit=100) :

```
{  
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{  
      "categorymembers":[  
         {  
            "pageid":5259784,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Animal geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":8670379,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Autobiogeography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":4254743,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Chorography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":177512,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Economic geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":7907104,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Footloose industry"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":5155886,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Geomorphometry"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":2596739,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Health geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":13372,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Human geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":1794929,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Military geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":5886597,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Philosophy of geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":23263,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Physical geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":1845092,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Political geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":711230,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Regional geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":42099944,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Satirical cartography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":33566568,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Settlement geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":9710174,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Transport geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":24644075,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Vernacular geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":5329197,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Visual geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":716309,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Cartography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":2021084,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Economic geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":2245786,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Geodemography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":1111700,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Human geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":7774333,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Military geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":2153059,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Physical geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":1898464,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Political geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":6645804,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Regional geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":44706236,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Settlement geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":6517504,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Topography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":1086902,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Toponymy"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":41335672,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Transportation geography"
         },
         {  
            "pageid":24727902,
            "ns":14,
            "title":"Category:Vernacular geography"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I really appreciate if you can point me to the right direction on how to solve this problem.

**Thank you all for your assistance and guidance.**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not just generate two files when you're parsing the JSON?

Comment: You might find the `in` operator useful: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details

Comment: The reason is these are all the title founds based on the json . When I extract I have extracted all the titles out but I do not know how to separate them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:

    data = []
    category = []

    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Category'):
            category.append(line)
        else:
            data.append(line)

    cat_file = open('category.txt', 'w')
    data_file = open('data.txt', 'w')

    cat_file.write(''.join(category))
    data_file.write(''.join(data))

    cat_file.close()
    data_file.close()
```

This reads the file `file.txt` line by line, and test if it begins with "Category". If it's the case, it adds the line to the `category` array, and if not, to the `data` array.

After processing the file, the program merges all the lines and write them to category.txt and data.txt.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: @windboy no problem, you can accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To test if a line in a file begins with  "Category:", you can simply do this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        if line[0:8] == "Category":
            <here your code that writes "Category:" lines in a new file>
        else:
            <here your code that writes all other lines in a new file>
```

Comment: Thank you very much alphabug for  the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  leekaiinthesky for telling me to use 'in'

```
f1 = open('List.text', 'r')
f2 = open('WordWithCat.text', 'w')
f3 = open('WordwithoutCat.text', 'w')
query = 'Category:'
lines = f1.read().splitlines()

for  line in lines:

    if query in line:
        f2.write(line+'\n')

    else:

        f3.write(line+'\n')
```

It turn out to be not as complicated as I thought it would be. Thank you all for your help and guidance.